# Update GPS every x seconds or every y meters

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

My application must get the coordinates every 100m or every 150 seconds. If the last position was less far then 80m (so i must have the new coordinate even if i'm still in the same place), the application can end correctly. I found the 
`requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener)`
but the minTime is just a hint (i get the new point every 100m, but if i stay in the same point, nothing happens). Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get an event within `minTime` time, you know you haven't moved and you can pretend you did get that event.

Comment: But if i move 90m from the last location, the application can't end, but if i don't get the new location, i can't know the distance

Comment: Use a smaller minDistance, then.

Comment: And smaller minTime while we're at it. You need better resolution if you want to make sure your application doesn't close prematurely.

Comment: i can do it, but i must save ALL my locations. So, even if i use a smaller minDist (50 for example), i can still move 40m away from the last point, but if the time doesn't work, i'll lose the last point

Comment: Don't log the location if the change is below what you need to log.

Comment: The problem is that i must log the last point too. I came here for this reason :) I just need a way to get the last location.

Comment: Is the last location that actual location, or the one before that if the user hasn't moved more than 100 meters?

Comment: The actual position. I can't find a way to get the actual position without the "onchange" event.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener)
```

In this you will also recieve a location may be similar to the previous one after every minTime interval look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: I read the documentation, but the minTime is useless because i get the new location just every 100 meters (and not after 150 seconds)

Comment: what time you passed to minTime

Comment: each location have captured time property use it how old it is

Comment: Ok, but now i lose the last point if the event dosn't start, so i need the get the last location.